# Set select menu default option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a select menu which is generated from an ng-repeat. I've noticed it starts on 3. This isnt ideal, how can I have it set to 1 child by default?

Something to note is I need to be able to get the index number from that room object for other non related code.

Plunker here: [LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/eBtqiyX5FVZlEmTdEk5F?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize the variable to 1.  (You initialized it to 3 in your code)

http://plnkr.co/edit/rld39zJIHwIg0mOe7p1u?p=preview

Could you be more specific about what you want to do in the 2nd part of your question?

Comment: Oops, silly mistake. Thanks. Dont worry about the second thing.